# how to handle datasets that have complicated logic and many fields?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a dataset, `dataset1` it has approximately 20 fields. **(not yet implemented)**

let's say for the purposes of this question, it has only 4 fields:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4
```

i would like my report to display all fields just like that:

```
field1[1], field2[1], field3[1], field4[1]
field1[2], field2[2]. field3[2], field4[2]
etc
```

because i will have complicated logic and a large number of fields, can i just break `dataset1` into `dataset1` and `dataset2` where:

```
dataset1=
field1, field2
```

and

```
dataset2=
field3, field4
```

and display the fields in the report like this

```
dataset1.field1[1], dataset1.field2[1], dataset2.field3[1], dataset2.field4[1]
dataset1.field1[2], dataset1.field2[2], dataset2.field3[2], dataset2.field4[2]
```

how does one deal with datasets that have complicated logic and a large number of fields?

Comment: Just use one dataset, don't over complicate things

Comment: what do you mean by "complicated logic"? why do you want to split your dataset?

Comment: @msmucker0527 make that into an answer and i'll buy it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the data set into two separate tables.  However, you need a key to combine them . . . the `1` and `2` in your example.

In this case, the query would look something like:

```
select d1.field1, d1.field2, d2.field3, d2.field4
from dataset1 d1 join
     dataset2 d2
     on d1.id = d2.id  -- or whatever the field is for connecting them
```

You can do the inverse as well.  That is, keep all the data in a single table, and then create views, such as:

```
create view dataset1 as
    select field1, field2
    from dataset;
```

I don't want to second guess why you are doing this. Columnar databases store each column separately (as if in a separate table), although they have highly optimized mechanisms for re-combining them.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do it in SSRS, this would still give you an SSRS dataset with a large number of fields